# How do I find my crawler user agent string?

Tags: web-crawler, user-agent

I currently run a directory website that I blog and do marketing for however I paid a freelancer to code the website.

I now have other websites asking for the "user agent string" of my site's crawler / bot (similar to then info shown here: https://airtable.com/shrh79V7TGie48DAm/tblJSPI6CzPrLXrS3) so that they can link to my website and need to know how to find this or what I need to do.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!
Megan

Comment: I'm deleting my answer from before and updating the question to better reflect what you are asking. I thought you were asking about your browser user agent, not your crawler / bot user agent.

Comment: Thank you Justin!